# Blender rigid body to Unreal Engine

Tags: export, rigidbody, unreal-engine

Im attempting to have a rigid body animation that I baked in blender play as one animation in Unreal. However when I export the objects and armature, they all appear as individual animations. Is there any way to have all of the animations grouped into one single animation?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately no. In Unreal Engine every object has its own animation can't be merged across objects (with FBX). For cinematic purposes there is the Alembic (ABC) format, may be it can handle it. Probably the best if you use the Rigid Body simulation in the game engine.

Comment: Thanks! I used ABC format and it worked perfectly. Huge help